# Jquery Autocomplete issue with source file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to use the autocomplete widget provided by jQuery-UI. This is my code but it does not seem to be working.

I have the following in my header:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/auto-complete.js"></script>
```

I then have my form with text input:

```
<input type="text" id="keyword" placeholder="Start typing to search..." name="keyword"/>
```

**The `auto-complete.js` file:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#keyword').autocomplete({
        source: 'suggest_name.php',
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

**The `suggest_name.php` file:**

```
echo "suggest name";
die();
```

Nothing happens. Any advice?

NOTE: Just tried supplying it with an array filled with static information and it is working, I don't know why it is not detecting my PHP script as a data source though.

Comment: Did you remember to also include jQuery? Have you checked the browser's console for errors? Debug my good man, debug!

Comment: I have included `jQuery` the `auto_complete.js` file is loading when the page loads up, I tested this by outputting text in the console using `console.log`

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle of what exact problem u r having

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First check if your request is actually being made, to check if the autocomplete is bound to your input.

Once you made clear that the request is actually being made:

You are returning just a string while **[the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)** states that you need te return an array of strings `["string","string2"]` OR an array of objects with a label and a value: `[{label: "label", value: "value"}, {label: "label2", value: "value2"}]`

The documentation is there for a reason and it has perfect examples of how everything works.

Comment: Don't be so condesending

Comment: It's not meant to be condescending, it was meant as a headsup. If i was trying to be condescending, i wouldn't actually tell you what the problem is, just tell you where to find it.

Comment: my bad, sorry about that. Appreciate the input.

Comment: Not a problem, hope it helped you get it right anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The following is not enough:

```
echo "suggest name";
```

Read the documentation of the [jQuery UI autocomplete's **`source`** parameter](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), the part where is says:

> **Array:** An array can be used for local data. There are two supported
>   formats:
>
> - An array of strings: `[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]`
> - An array of objects with label and value properties: `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`
>
> The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will
>   be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item. If
>   just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if you
>   provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the
>   label.
>
> [...]
>
> **String:** When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that
>   string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. [...]
>   The data itself can be
>   in the same format as the local data described above.

Long story short, at minimum you must output something like:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode(array("suggest name"));
```

Output:

```
["suggest name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a **absolute** URL to your PHP program, which generates the autocomplete data, in parameter *source*.

Please check with browsers developer tools if a xhr request is sent and a correct HTTP response is received.

Comment: no you don't need an absolute path, relative is fine. Checking for the xhr request however, good call!